# GraphRequest is null after getRequestForPagedResults method

Tags: android, json, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I am building an application that **fetches the images** of a facebook user. I have parsed the returned **JSONObject**, extracted the URL of the images and load them into a GridView.

The Problem is that the JSONObject have link to second pages to fetch the remaining images's.

Here is my code:

```
final GraphRequest.Callback graphCallback = new GraphRequest.Callback(){
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();
            GraphRequest newRequest = response.getRequestForPagedResults(GraphResponse.PagingDirection.NEXT);
            JSONObject object = request.getGraphObject();
        }
    };

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "images");
parameters.putString("limit", "50");
Bundle tagged = new Bundle();
tagged.putString("type", "tagged");

final GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest( AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/" + profile.getId() + "/photos", tagged,
 HttpMethod.GET, graphCallback
);
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

Here is the value of the newRequest:

> {Request:  accessToken: {AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:> [user_friends, user_photos, public_profile]}, graphPath: null, graphObject: null, httpMethod: GET, parameters: Bundle[{}]}

And the value of the JSONObject "object" is :

> null

**how to implement pagination using FacebookSDK**

Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i found the solution. First of all the newRequest object is **not null**. When I debug the code, I looked for the difference between the newRequest (GraphRequest) and the request (GraphRequest).

There are 2 things missing:

1. I should the method callBack should be declared.
2. The GraphPath should not be null as shown above.
3. The Bundle parameters are an issue, but i need it to extract the URL of the images.

Therefore, my code becomes as follows:

```
final GraphRequest.Callback graphCallback = new GraphRequest.Callback(){
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "images");
                parameters.putString("limit", "50");
                jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();
                GraphRequest newRequest =      response.getRequestForPagedResults(GraphResponse.PagingDirection.NEXT);
                newRequest.setGraphPath("/" + profile.getId() + "/photos");
                newRequest.setCallback(this);
                newRequest.setParameters(parameters);
                newRequest.executeAsync();
        }
    };
```

**This is how Pagination is implemented with facebookSDK**